# How to set focus require attribute on <input> tag in React

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have login/register forms that have several `input` tags in it.

I would like to set focus and require attribute on first `input` tag when I open this form.

I tried jQuery and JavaScript code and it works fine on require attribute.

When `input` tag's values are empty, it says warning alert but setting focus doesn't work.

Below is my code.

```js
<form className="Form_login">
    <h2>Login</h2>
    {location.state?.message && 
        (<div className="Message_login">
            {location.state?.message}
        </div>)}
    {error && <div className="Alert_login">{error}</div>}
    <label className="InputGroup_login" htmlFor="email">
        Email:
        <input className="Input_login"
               id="email"
               type="email"
               value={email}
               onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
        />
    </label>
    <label className="InputGroup_login" htmlFor="password">
        Password:
        <input className="Input_login"
               id="password"
               type="password"
               value={password}
               onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
        />
    </label>
    <div className="ButtonContainer_login">
        <button className="Button_addhome Input_addhome" 
                onClick={handleSubmit}>Login</button>
        <Link to = "/" 
              className="Button_link Input_addhome" 
              style={{textAlign:"center"}}>Cancel</Link>
    </div>
    <div style={{ textAlign: "center", paddingTop: "1rem" }}>
        <span>
            forgot password or <Link to="/register">register</Link>
        </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set require attribute simply adding `required` in your input tags.
And also set focuse on first `input` tag by adding `autofocus` attribute in your input tag.

```
   <input className="Input_login
          id="email"
          type="email"
          value={email}
          onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          required
          autofocus
    />
```

**Note:** The `autofocus` attribute cannot be used on inputs of type `hidden`, since hidden inputs cannot be focused.

Comment: Thank you. It is simple and working well.

Comment: You can find more about attribute of react in [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#autofocus)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try jQuery based method:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form:first *:input[type!=hidden]:first').focus();
});
```

Comment: Instead of posting another answer, you could edit the other one. Or delete the other one now, since it isn't needed.